# How to load firefox xpcom to newly created firefox profile using selenium webdriver

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon

I have created new firefox profile using selenium webdriver as in [web driver documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#firefox-driver). I have created firebug extension also, but I cannot access firefox xpcom features then. Is there any method to do so? I am getting error below in firefox console.

`NS_ERROR_XPC_JAVASCRIPT_ERROR_WITH_DETAILS: [JavaScript Error: "a is null" {file: "file:///C:/Users/RMDESI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3659154916358123849webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/prompt_service.js" line: 7637}]'[JavaScript Error: "a is null" {file: "file:///C:/Users/RMDESI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3659154916358123849webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/prompt_service.js" line: 7637}]' when calling method: [nsIPromptService::prompt]`

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(); 
profile.setPreference("security.xpconnect.plugin.unrestricted",true);
```